# JS global variable "lost" inside function?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables

For some reasons, I had to declare a variable at the end of the document, here's how it looks:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- other libraries are here -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myImportantVariable = someIntValue;
</script>

<script src="/my/own/scripts.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Now, inside `scripts.js` I want to use that variable, but it becomes undefined at some point:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myDOMelement").someExistingAndWorkingFunction(function() {
        // <--- here myImportantVariable value is correct
        myOtherFunction($(this).val());
    });
});

function myOtherFunction($valueArgument)
{
    // <--- here myImportantVariable is undefined
}
```

I'm not sure, what is happening. I also tried declaring the variable at the end (after all the scripts are linked) and inside `document ready` block, nothing works. I thought it should be accessible from the function, but it is not. Can you explain to me, why?

**EDIT** to answer questions in comments:

- I can't declare `myImportantVariable` inside `scripts.js`, it's dynamic
- `myDomElement` is the id of an input
- `$(this).val()` is correctly fetched (checked on debugger inside the block, where `myImportantVariable` is still correct)
- and it is correctly passed to `myOtherFunction` (checked on debugger at the beginning of the `myOtherFunction`)
- on the very beginning of the `myOtherFunction` (checked on... correct! Debugger!), `myImportantVariable` is suddenly undefined

Comment: Global variables are definitely available. Two possibilities: your code that finds the value undefined runs *before* the script that sets the value, or some code is inadvertently changing the value. Variables don't just change for no reason.

Comment: @DevDig — Why do you doubt that? (Especially given the OP has explicitly said it **is** available in part of it)

Comment: `myImportantVariable` should be available in the `script.js`. Can your show us what's happening in the `myOtherFunction` and what is the `$(this).val()` value output?

Comment: @Quentin Forget it, I misread the code

Comment: Even if I don't know the whole code, but I bet a dollor `$(this).val()` is the problem.

Comment: I hope I answered your questions at the end of my question.  
@Pointy could that be the case, if the variable is available inside the function that is calling another, but not inside that another (called) function? I mean that second function is not called before...

Comment: @michelgotta I can't see why you'd think that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @b174008 No. Global variables are **global**.  It's *really* hard to give useful answers if you don't post the actual code; for all I know, the code you posted here is fine while the real code has some typo or something that you haven't noticed.

Comment: @vlaz With the infos given, one thing that could really "set" `myImportantVariable` to `undefined` is the `$(this).val()`. Because `this` is maybe not what you expected to be inside the `someExistingAndWorkingFunction` scope. Maybe I was just kidding. I think we need more code to give useful answers.

Comment: OK, I really have NO idea, what is going on. I cannot give you the full code, but on the small fiddle it works: https://jsfiddle.net/1au7Lwj7/   
I give up, I will do some ugly hack here and remember it for future, thanks.